# BOOK N\nCHAPTER I for first chapter of each book/part?

Tags: luatex, memoir

Consider the MWE:

```
% vim: spell spelllang=en
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\emergencystretch 3em

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\book{BOOK}

\chapter{FOO}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

that on page 1 results in:

[image: book.png]

and on page 3:

[image: chapter.png]

What I'd like, is something akin to:

## BOOK I

### Chapter I

#### FOO

On one page, per book-n/chapter-1-in-that-book pairing (chapter numbers reset with each book). The books are, in truth, without title, so the 'BOOK' can be omitted.

I'm using lualatex due to the substance of the work using a fair amount of unicode and font-related trickery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code in the `\chapterheadstart` part.

In the following I use `oneside` and `a6paper` just to make smaller pictures.

The idea is to reset the chapter number when `book` steps, but it's not necessary to issue `\book` with a title, just stepping the counter is enough.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a6paper]{memoir}

\counterwithin*{chapter}{book}
\chapterstyle{thatcher}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=1
    \vbox to 0pt{
      \vss
      \centering
      BOOK \thebook\par
      \vspace{5ex}%
    }%
    \nointerlineskip
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\newbook}{\stepcounter{book}}



\begin{document}

\newbook

\chapter{FOO}

text

\chapter{BAZ}

\newbook

\chapter{AGAIN}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works for me. I didn't mention this in the OP but I would have preferred to keep the book/chapter divisions in the index/toc, but that's an easy enough fix:

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{book}{BOOK \thebook}

right after \ifnum\value{chapter}=1